# React-redux, can't use connect with my root component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I can't use connect, with export in App component. No error is thrown, the app starts normally... but all my links in my navbar stop to work (???). The url changes, but the main page is always displayed, like it would break the routing.  Here is my code:

```
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Layout from './hoc/Layout/Layout';
import BurgerBuilder from './containers/BurgerBuilder/BurgerBuilder';
import Checkout from './containers/Checkout/Checkout';
import Orders from './containers/Orders/Orders';
import Auth from './containers/Auth/Auth';
import * as actions from './store/actions'

class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Layout>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/checkout" component={Checkout} />
            <Route path="/orders" component={Orders} />
            <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />
            <Route path="/" exact component={BurgerBuilder} />
          </Switch>
        </Layout>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
      anything: ()=>dispatch(actions.logout())
  }
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
//export default App;
```

If I comment the 'connect' part, like this:

```
//export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
export default App;
```

everything runs ok and all my links are working fine. Why can't I use 'connect' in my App component? I know I'm not dispatching any actions through props, but it should work nontheless, as far as I'm concerned.

Below is my index.js file, which uses th App component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import burgerBuilderReducer from './store/reducers/burgerBuilder';
import orderReducer from './store/reducers/order';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    burgerBuilder: burgerBuilderReducer,
    order: orderReducer
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
));

const app = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render( app, document.getElementById( 'root' ) );
registerServiceWorker();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it. The solution was to wrap both my App and Layout components (layout holds my navigation items) with "withRouter":

```
export default withRouter(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Layout));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'
...
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (bindActionCreators({
    actionName: () => ({type:'SOME_ACTION', payload: 'SOME_PAYLOAD'}),
    doLogout: () => actions.logout(),
}, dispatch))
```

EDIT: Do this changes to your `App.js`

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/checkout" component={Checkout} />
        <Route path="/orders" component={Orders} />
        <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />
        <Route path="/" exact component={BurgerBuilder} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck. The result is the same, the app compiles and launches, routing doesn't work, no errors in console

Comment: Routing does't work at all or just only when you logout ?

Comment: All routing is broken, can't navigate at all, to any page. If I export the App without 'Connect' everything starts to work right away

Comment: Everything looks ok, beside one thing, I think you should use ```BrowserRouter``` to wrap the ```Switch```, i had a similar problem in the past.

Comment: If do it this way, I get an error:
_You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>_
If I wrap also <Layout> with <BrowserRouter>, the error is gone, but the issue persists. Next, I tried to remove the <Switch> and made all my routes exact, but the result is the same.

Comment: Did you removed ```BrowserRouter``` from ```index.js``` ? Also , I checked an old project. I passed ```history``` object to ```BrowserRouter```, check [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#readme)

Comment: Yes, I removed it along with the import, and moved it to app.js I also came along a very similar issue on this github page:
https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/2456
But I don't really understand the proposed solution